# Export a postgresql database

Tags: database, postgresql, pg-dumpall

I want to export a postgresql database named "kd" with all roles, tablespaces, etc. I run the command  `pg_dumpall -U sce -h localhost -p 5450 -d kd > /tmp/db.sql` I get the error

```
 pg_dumpall: missing "=" after "kd5" in connection info string
```

I run the command `pg_dumpall -U sce -h localhost -p 5450 > /tmp/db.sql`
I get the error

```
pg_dumpall: query was: SELECT oid, rolname, rolsuper, rolinherit, rolcreaterole, rolcreatedb, rolcanlogin, rolconnlimit, rolpassword, rolvaliduntil, rolreplication, pg_catalog.shobj_description(oid, 'pg_authid') as rolcomment, rolname = current_user AS is_current_user FROM pg_authid ORDER BY 2
```

How can fix this problem ?

Comment: `pg_dumpall` will dump the entire cluster so you don't need the `-d` . If you only want the `kd` database then `pg_dump -U sce -h localhost -p 5450 -d kd > /tmp/db.sql` and then `pg_dumpall -U sce -h localhost -p 5450 -g > pg_globals.sql` to get the cluster globals e.g. roles and tablespaces.

Comment: the same problem

Comment: Is `-U sce` a superuser? The user dumping the database(s) has to have sufficient privileges to access all the objects in the database(s).

Comment: I get the message "pg_dumpall: query was: SELECT oid, rolname, rolsuper, rolinherit, rolcreaterole, rolcreatedb, rolcanlogin, rolconnlimit, rolpassword, rolvaliduntil, rolreplicat                                                                             ion, pg_catalog.shobj_description(oid, 'pg_authid') as rolcomment, rolname = cur                                                                             rent_user AS is_current_user FROM pg_authid ORDER BY 2"

Comment: sce is the user that have access to database

Comment: I get the error pg_dumpall: query failed: ERROR: permission denied for relationship pg_authid

Comment: And the error messages are telling you that the user does not have the necessary privileges to dump the database. Having access to a database is not the same as having the privileges to dump. Select a user that does, in other words a superuser.

Comment: I want to use only pg_dumpall  to export all databases with roles

Comment: 1) That is not what your code shows and your text says: "I want to export a postgresql database named "kd". 2) The issue you are having is with permissions, you need to deal with that first.

Comment: I fixed the problem with permission